# Can you improve code - iteration in 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, for-loop

I already know that iteration over array in python is very slow. Can you improve this code, if possible. I just want to take values from numpy array, which are bigger than constat (1.4) and otherwise set zero.

```
def array_max(a):
   b = a
   for i in range(a.shape[0]):
      for j in range(a.shape[1]):
         for k in range(a.shape[2]):
            if a[i, j, k] <= 1.4:
               b[i,j,k] = 0
    return b
```

Comment: In your current code, `b` is going to be a reference to the same array as `a`, which is probably not what you intend. You're modifying `a` in place, not returning a new, modified version of it. If you want to make `b` a copy of `a` rather than just a reference, you need to do so explicitly (e.g. with `b = a.copy()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the builtin [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function which checks the condition on condition an array element-wise and assigns a value to the resulting array accordingly:

> **`np.where(condition[, x, y])`**
>
> *Parameters:*
>
> - `condition`: array_like, bool - Where `True`, yield `x`, otherwise yield `y`.
> - `x`, `y`: array_like - Values from which to choose. `x`, `y` and `condition` need to be broadcastable to some shape.

```
>>> np.where(a <= 1.4, 0, a)
```

Answer (score 6):

You should index directly:

```
a[a < 1.4] = 0
```

The line `b = a` is superfluous because it does not make a copy, just assigns to a new name.

If you wanted to create a new array rather than modifying the original, you can do it in a couple of different ways:

```
b = a.copy()
b[a < 1.4] = 0
```

Or

```
b = np.zeros_like(a)
mask = a >= 1.4
b[mask] = a[mask]
```

Or

```
b = np.where(a <= 1.4, 0, a)
```